# PostgreSQL SQL output by slice data using logic operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, logic, operators

I need to upload from PostgreSQL data from invoice, 'billing_address' and 'billing_city', and it must be between 2009-09-01 to 2009-09-30 (sept.2009) in 'invoice_date'.

In result must be 2 columns only 'billing_address' and 'billing_city'. Cannot use BETWEEN in simulator, please understand. It's a simulator exercise to slice data by knowing logic operators, and using CAST to convert date.

So I wrote a code:

```
SELECT billing_address,
    billing_city,
    CAST(invoice_date AS date)        
FROM invoice
WHERE NOT billing_country = 'USA'
    AND NOT billing_country = 'Brazil'
    AND total > 2
    AND invoice_date >= '2009.09.01'
    AND invoice_date <= '2009.09.30'
```

It returns me:

billing_address     billing_city    invoice_date
696 Osborne Street  Winnipeg        2009-09-16

And a simulator indicates me that result must be 2 columns ('billing_address' and 'billing_city'). How to hide column 'invoice_date' from output, or correct my code if needed.

Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

change the . in the date to - and add ::timestamp

```
SELECT billing_address,
    billing_city,
    CAST(invoice_date AS date)        
FROM invoice
WHERE NOT billing_country = 'USA'
    AND NOT billing_country = 'Brazil'
    AND total > 2
    AND invoice_date >= '2009-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
    AND invoice_date < '2009-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp
```

Comment: I receive this: operator does not exist: character varying >= timestamp without time zone

Please advice

https://pastebin.com/cbkRu1r3

Comment: try this : 
CAST(invoice_date AS timestamp)

Comment: Thank you for participation. I just got answer from my tutor, that to receive 2 columns at output, I don't need to use `CAST(invoice_date AS date)`. Should I delete my question or keep it as it is. 
Big thanks for answering and helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT billing_address,
    billing_city
FROM invoice
WHERE total > 2
    AND (NOT billing_country = 'USA'
    AND NOT billing_country = 'Brazil')
    AND (CAST(invoice_date AS date) >= '2009.09.01'
    AND invoice_date <= '2009.09.30');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?